# Python 2.7.3 installation on xUbuntu

Tags: python

I downloaded python sources. When I do configure, everything fine, but when I do make, it says that Tcl/Tk library not found. Where can I find all packages required by python?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any particular reason you are not just installing the package?

Comment: Also, this should probably go on http://superuser.com/ or http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: @Lattyware To be sure, I'd like to install exactly what is posted on Python website. Previously I had many troubles with other things in repositories (like eclipse IDE) and now I'm always using exactly what authors provided to avoid problems.

Comment: TBH, you are far more likely to have problems with your own build than with the build provided by the distro maintainers.

Comment: @aix I can't upvote that enough.

Comment: @gasan:  The repository version of Python works *just fine*.  Don't let a bad experience sour you.

Comment: Also, if you want to compile everything by hand, I'd run a different distro. Ubuntu (and by extension, Xubuntu) is not designed with that in mind. Something like Arch or Gentoo which have easy ways of constructing your own packages (ABS/portage).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [DSC file](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python2.7/python2.7_2.7.2-5ubuntu1.dsc) for the Ubuntu `python2.7` package to find the `Build-Depends` and `apt-get install` all of them before building Python.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.tcl.tk/software/tcltk/download.html

This has worked every time I needed it to.  Make sure to read the `INSTALL` and/or `README` files as I remember it has a somewhat non-standard method of installation...